# text entered in EditText does not change into password immediately

Tags: android, passwords, android-edittext

the password when entered by user does not change into * immedietly and plain text is displayed for 5 secs or so.I don't want this as my making a custom lock screen otherwise others can see the password entered.
I'm using

> android:password="true"

kindly help

Comment: check if the visiblePassword property is set true

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is how it is on all mobile platforms, and it's the "normal" way, because of the small, virtual keyboard you may introduce the wrong character. Nevertheless if you really want to modify that you'll have to create you own EditText, which will extend android's EditText.